# Is there a better way to represent uint8 data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, uint, usrp

I have a question regarding the representation of the uint8 data.

I have a MATLAB MAT file where uint8 data are saved.

The MAT file is reading into Python using `scipy.io.loadmat()` and a dictionary is formed. 
The array corresponding to the data filed of the MAT file is extracted from the dictionary.
The array looks like:

```
array[[162],[122],...[135],dtype:uint8]
```

After that, this array is saved into txt format for later file reading.
However, the data in the txt file is double precision. For example, `uint8` data `162` is saved as `1.620000000000000000e+02`. This is not what i want, because it would occupy too much memory.

What I need is that each one byte from `source_file.read()` corresponds to one `uint8` data.

Is there a better way to represent the uint8 data?  Convert uint8 to string is possible but still take 2-3 bytes.

Comment: What method are you using to save the file?

Comment: Why is the data written to the text file as floating point?

Comment: @John, i previously use 'numpy.savetxt()' to save the array.

Comment: @Warren, as Dougal just mentioned, the default fmt argument is '%.18e'. That's why there are so many digits.

Answer (score 7):

You're presumably using [`numpy.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html), which has default `fmt` argument `'%.18e'`, meaning "in exponential format with 18 digits of precision."

You could change it to something that'll spit out an integer (e.g. `fmt='%d'`), but that's still quite inefficient in terms of file space usage (since it's an ASCII-encoded integer).

[`numpy.save`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) is in a much more efficient binary format, which is much closer to what you're asking for, though it includes some headers ([format description](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/npy-format.txt#L152)). If you want just the binary data then `tostring` [as suggested by dbaupp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13018843/344821) is the way to go:

```
with open('outfile', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(the_array.tostring())
```

Comment: Thanks Dougal, both of numpy.save and tostring are very useful. As u said, considering the header, tostring seems to be even better in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Numpy has [`tostring()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tostring.html) and [`fromstring()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) which convert between a `ndarray` data structure and a binary string. E.g.

```
> a = numpy.array([162,122,135], dtype=numpy.uint8)
> a.tostring()
'\xa2z\x87'
```

(That string is `['\xa2', 'z', '\x87']`, the `\x..` represents a single byte.)